# xor with leading zero issue in python

Tags: python, string, hex, bit, xor

I want to xor two hex-format strings in python, like '45' and '4e'. But how do I keep the leading zero if the result is in [0x00, 0x0f]?

```
hex(int('45', 16) ^ int('4e', 16))
```

gives '0xb', while I'm expecting '0x0b'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `"0x{:02x}".format(int('45', 16) ^ int('4e', 16))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method is to use [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
>>> '0x{:02x}'.format(0xb)
'0x0b'
```

Comment: Thanks. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your expectations from the function [hex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex).

`hex()` only produces a string presentation for output.

Proof:

```
>>> hex(2)+hex(15)
'0x20xf'
```

Which is utter nonsense of course since the string value of `hex(2)` and the string value of `hex(15)` are just being appended together.

The solution is to do your arithmetic clear though to the end THEN select how you wish to present the result.

The result of your calculation is 11:

```
>>> int('45', 16) ^ int('4e', 16)
11
```

Then format it.

Old way:

```
>>> '0x%0.2x' % 11
'0x0b'
```

Newer way:

```
>>> '0x'+format(11,'02x')
'0x0b'
```

Or:

```
>>> '0x{:02x}'.format(11)
'0x0b'
```

Answer (score 0):

For a relatively small number of values (like 0x00-0xff), one practical as well as very efficient method to convert the result into hexadecimal string the way you wish is to build and use a look-up table. The `'0x%02x' % v`expression employed in building the table would also be a simple and fairly concise way of converting a single value just once.

```
>>> HEXDEC = ['0x%02x' % v for v in (x+y for x in range(16) for y in range(16))]
>>> HEXDEC[int('45', 16) ^ int('4e', 16)]
'0x0b'
>>>
```